# Origin access identity and S3 permission

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

From http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html ,

[image]

I have already created an OAI, as shown in this screenshot

[image]

Am I supposed to grant the permission to the OAI via the permission section here? If so, do I expect to see the OAI in the dropdown box?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create/modify a bucket policy or ACL to use the OAI.  See near the bottom of this page for step-by-step instructions:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html